# Mobile Legends not working in android x86

Tags: android-x86

I I'm trying to play mlbb on my laptop with android x86. But after the first extradition the screen goes black after the logo and it says keeps stop working. I enabled native bridge and tried other is like prime and phoenix. It works on emulator but slow. How can I get it running?

If this is not site for it. Please refer

Comment: As you pointed out in a comment that Mlbb is only available for arm7, it's unlikely to run on x86 due to architecture differences.

Comment: But android x86 has arm compitibality. And arms games like alto packo runs well. I also saw some people  on youtube play it on phoenix os. There was also a edieted apk for android x86 2 years ago.

Comment: Ah, OK – I wasn't aware of that.